# How can I render an element when I clicked the function in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

How can I render an element when I clicked the function in ReactJS?

I have a component `Notifications` and imported to the main component. I coded a function to check the validation and render the `Notifications` component:

```
const submit = () => {
      if (name === '' || email === '' || phone === '' || subject === '' || message === '') {
        setStateOfInput();
        //I don't know how to render the <Notifications/> from here
      }
      else if (email.indexOf('@') === -1) {
        //And here
        setStateOfInput();
      }
...
```

I used `return ( <Notifications/> )` but it wasn't working!

I'm new to ReactJs so thanks for all your help!

Comment: You don't "render it from there". The typical approach would be to set a flag that indicates it should be rendered then conditionally render it along with the rest of the component.

Answer (score 1):

I would set a state inside to control of rendering your component but if you really want to return in function you can do something like that

```
const submit = () => {
      if (name === '' || email === '' || phone === '' || subject === '' || message === '') {
        setStateOfInput();
        return <Notifications />
      }
      else if (email.indexOf('@') === -1) {
        setStateOfInput();
        return <SomeComponent />
      }
...
```

Inside the main return of the component you can call this function

```
    return (.......

<div>{submit()}</div>

.....
)
```